# Exception thriwn: write access violation. p was 0x1140000

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently working on a c++ program in which I have a large array of size 100,000. I have filled it with sequential values from 1 to 100,000. I want to make this a prime number array, so I want to go through and delete multiples of 2, 3, 5. So, my logic is to start at 4, delete it, increment the index by 2 and delete it, and continue until the end of the array. Well, in my loop where I am deleting multiples at line *p = 0, I get the exception thrown. When I change the size of the array to 100 or even 1000, I do not get this exception, and it successfully deletes all of the multiples. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes:
void generateBigArray(int *, int);
void deleteMultsOf2(int *, int);

// Fill up the array with values 1 - 100,000.
void generateBigArray(int *p, int size)
{
int count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *p = count++;
    p = p + 1; // bump to the next location.
}
}


void deleteMultsOf2(int *p, int size)
{
p = p + 3; // start at 4 to zero it out
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    {
        *p = 0;
        p = p + 2;
    }
}
}

int main()
{
// an array to hold prime numbers from 1 - 100,000
const int BIGSIZE = 100000;
int bigAry[BIGSIZE];

// a pointer for the prime number array.
int *bigptr;
bigptr = bigAry;

generateBigArray(bigptr, BIGSIZE);
deleteMultsOf2(bigptr, BIGSIZE);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` increments by one but `p` increments by two in `deleteMultsOf2`. This means, you're iterating twice as far as you're allowed.

Comment: Don't mess with pointer arithmetic if you don't have to. You could have just done some calculations with the indices and avoided this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're iterating `size` times (e.g., 100000), but each time, you increment your pointer by `2`. So if you start at `p + 3`, by the time you get to the last iteration, you'll be at 200003.

Increment your look by 2 also, and initialize with `i = 3` and it should solve your problem:

```
for (int i = 3; i < size; i += 2) {
    // ...
}
```

As for why it works with some sizes: it's not necessarily working, it's just avoiding an access violation. Pointer overruns are tricky to diagnose sometimes, because they don't always created errors at the point where the problem is.

If you happen to run past the applications memory space, then you'll get an access violation, and the operating system will kill your program. But the operating system doesn't care what you do *within* your applications memory space. So depending on how that space is laid out, you may run over entirely into application memory, which will probably wreak havoc down the road and have you scratching your head as you keep getting failures, never in the same place twice.

For this program, it's probably more likely you'll get access violations with larger sizes because you're accessing more memory and therefore are more likely to run outside the application bounds.

Comment: `i` should start at `3` though since `p` also starts at `p + 3`.

Comment: Thank you!!! After changing i++ to 1+=2, it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked! Please note @tkausl's correction about the initial value of `i`.